# Mapeamento ManyToMany. Problema no bean

Tags: java, banco-de-dados, jsf, jpa

Após fazer o relacionamento ManyToMany entre tabelas não sei como salvar no meu bean. Tenho uma classe cadastro de prazos que tem um ou mais advogados cuidado desse prazo. O advogado tbm pode ser responsável por mais de um prazo. Quero fazer que qndo entro no cadastro desse advogado ele mostre os prazos que o advogado é responsável, da mesma forma no prazo. Futuramente esses advogados serão alertado por e-mail da data do prazo.

Fiz o seguinte mapeamento na minha classe `prazo`:

```
@ManyToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
@JoinTable(name = "prazo_advogado", joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "prazo_id"),
        inverseJoinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "advogado_id"))
private List<Advogado> advogados;
```

Classe `advogado`:

```
@ManyToMany(mappedBy = "advogados")
private List<Prazo> prazos;
```

No meu `xhtml` de cadastro de prazo tenho o campo advogado. Não sei com fazer referência ao advogado(maior duvida):

```
 <p:outputLabel value="Advogado" for="advogado" />
              <p:autoComplete id="advogado" size="40" dropdown="true"
                              value="#{cadastroPrazoBean.advogado.nome}" completeMethod="#{cadastroPrazoBean.completarAdvogado}"
                                var="advogado" itemLabel="#{advogado.nome}" itemValue="advogado" forceSelection="true" />
```

Meu bean:

```
public class CadastroPrazoBean implements Serializable {

private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

private Prazo prazo;
private Advogado advogado;


private List<Prazo> listPrazos;

@Inject
private Clientes clientes;

@Inject
private Prazos prazos;

@Inject
private Advogados advogados;

@Inject
private CadastroPrazoService cadastroPrazoService;

public CadastroPrazoBean() {
    prazo = new Prazo();
    advogado = new Advogado();

}

public String salvar() {
    this.prazo = cadastroPrazoService.salvar(this.prazo);
    FacesUtil.addInfoMessage("Prazo salvo com sucesso!");

    return "/pesquisa/pesquisaPrazo.xhtml";
}

 public List<Cliente> completarCliente(String nome) {
    return this.clientes.porNome(nome);
}

 public List<Advogado> completarAdvogado(String nome) {
    return this.advogados.porNome(nome);
}

 public List listagemPrazo(){

     listPrazos = prazos.listaPrazo();
     return this.listPrazos;
 }


public Prazo getPrazo() {
    return prazo;
}

public void setPrazo(Prazo prazo) {
    this.prazo = prazo;
}

public Advogado getAdvogado() {
    return advogado;
}

public void setAdvogado(Advogado advogado) {
    this.advogado = advogado;
}
```

}

Classe `dao`:

```
public List<Advogado> porNome(String nome) {
    return this.manager.createQuery("from Advogado "
            + "where upper(nome) like :nome", Advogado.class)
            .setParameter("nome", nome.toUpperCase() + "%")
            .getResultList();
}
```

Não sei se a forma que estou desenvolvendo é a melhor forma, essa é minha grande dúvida.  Já li alguns livros de mapeamento com JPA mas não tem exemplos com interação com a página.

Classe converter

`@FacesConverter(forClass = Advogado.class)
public class AdvogadoConverter implements Converter {`

```
@Inject
private Advogados advogados;

@Override
public Object getAsObject(FacesContext context, UIComponent component, String value) {
    Advogado retorno = null;

    if (StringUtils.isNotBlank(value)) {
        retorno = this.advogados.porId(new Long(value));
    }

    return retorno;
}

@Override
public String getAsString(FacesContext context, UIComponent component, Object value) {
    if (value != null) {
        Long codigo = ((Advogado) value).getId();
        String retorno = (codigo == null ? null : codigo.toString());

        return retorno;
    }

    return "";
}
```

}

Comment: Não entendi a sua dúvida. O CadastroPrazoBean não deveria ter um prazo  ao invés de um advogado? O mapeamento ManyToMany parece estar certo. O problema está em como salvar um prazo no banco de dados, é isso?

Comment: @SérgioMucciaccia Isso mesmo, como salvo no banco. Minha duvida como faço a interação no bean com relacionamento entre tabelas e como chamo no meu xhtml. Meu bean tem o prazo e advogado.

Comment: @SérgioMucciaccia No meu xhtml estou chamando assim o advogado:

`  value="#{cadastroPrazoBean.advogado.nome}"`

Answer (score 1):

Dentro do seu objeto prazo tem uma lista de advogados certo?
Para salvar um prazo junto com as referências para os seus advogados é só pegar esses advogados do banco de dados com o find() e adicioná-los na lista de advogados do seu objeto prazo e depois salvar o prazo!
Ao salvar o prazo o seu provedor de JPA vai olhar essa lista e adicionar as devidas linhas na tabela prazo_advogado automaticamente.

Então é só adicionar os advogados na lista, o que pode ser feito com um botão do lado do autocomplete por exemplo:

```
public void buttonAction(ActionEvent actionEvent) {
    prazo.getAdvogados().add(advogado);
}
```

Esse advogado seria o selecionado no autocomplete, mas para isso o seu p:autoComplete teria que selecionar um objeto advogado inteiro e não apenas o nome, então você teria que fazer um converter. Olhe o exemplo Pojo (o autocomplete escrito Pojo à esquerda) no primefaces showcase:

http://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/input/autoComplete.xhtml

Resumindo na sua classe CadastroPrazoBean deve ter um objeto advogado e um objeto prazo. Quando o cliente completar o autocomplete o objeto advogado será atualizado para o escolhido e quando o botão for apertado esse advogado será incluído na lista de advogados do objeto prazo, daí quando estiver tudo pronto é só salvar o objeto prazo.

Comment: Obrigado até o momento pela ajuda, já me ajudou bastante. Esqueci de mencionar que já tinha um converter.  Está dando a seguinte msg: `model.Advogado cannot be cast to java.lang.String` Estou postando meu converte do advogado.Obrigado desde já